# Looking display in Loop Array

Tags: javascript, arraylist

I have 3 variables in this format, I want output Product Array Format.

```
Name: Rahul, Mukesh, Nitish
Price: 75, 80, 90
Quantity: 1, 2, 4
```

Looking to Display Product Output:

```js
// Tried this code
function GetListOfMyCartProducts() {
  var products = [];
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    productNumber = productNumber + 1;
    var product = {
      'Name': Name,
      'Price': Price,
      'Quantity': Quantity

    }
    products.push(product);
  }
  return products
}
```

OutPut Looking -

Product:

```
[
   {name: 'Rahu', price: '75', quantity: '1'}, 
   {name: 'Mukesh' , price: '80', quantity: '2'}, 
   {name: 'Nitish' , price: '90', quantity: '4'}, 
]
```

Comment: Where do you define the variables, `Name`, `Price` and `Quantity`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl . Name: Rahul, Mukesh, Nitish
Price: 75, 80, 90
Quantity: 1, 2, 4

Comment: What data are you looping through? What is the expected output, is it supposed to be an array or an object?

Comment: @RohitKashyap Yes in Array loop, Product: [{name: 'Rahu', price: '75', quantity: '1'}, {name: 'Mukesh' , price: '80', quantity: '2'}, {name: 'Nitish' , price: '90', quantity: '4'},

Comment: Edit your question and write the correct format.

Comment: @RohitKashyap Updated it

Comment: @Rahul, What format is the input supposed to be?

Comment: @RohitKashyap, See in question, Product Array

Comment: @Rahul, you have not asked the question in the correct format, anyways, will the sizes of the all the arrays be the same? i.e the name, price and quantity array?

Comment: @RohitKashyap Correct

Answer (score 0):

This is done with minimal effort. I changed a few things:

- Fixed the variable assignment at the top
- Looped over `i` and removed the `productNumber`, because that was incorrect
- Indexed the variables properly.

```js
let Name     = [ 'Rahul', 'Mukesh', 'Nitish' ];
let Price    = [      75,       80,       90 ];
let Quantity = [       1,        2,        4 ];

console.log(GetListOfMyCartProducts());

function GetListOfMyCartProducts() {
  var products = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Name.length; i++) {
    products.push({
      'Name': Name[i],
      'Price': Price[i],
      'Quantity': Quantity[i]
    });
  }
  return { 'Products' : products };
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

#### A better approach

You do not need to know about any "variables" in this version, because the scope is the data object.

```js
let rawData = {
  "Name"     : [ "Rahul", "Mukesh", "Nitish" ],
  "Price"    : [      75,       80,       90 ],
  "Quantity" : [       1,        2,        4 ]
};

console.log(getListOfMyCartProducts(rawData, 'Products'));

function getListOfMyCartProducts(data, root) {
  let keys = Object.keys(data), first = data[keys[0]];
  return { [root] : first.map((_, index) => {
    return keys.reduce((obj, key) => Object.assign(obj, { [key] : data[key][index] }), {});
  })};
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```